# HTML files are viewed in the browser instead of the Eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse

When I try to view HTML files (e.g. a.xhtml) in my project they are launched in the browser instead of the Eclipse editor.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only to open the file with the Eclipse editor a single time, then right-click the file, and select Open with with the correct editor.

However, if you want to define file associations for Eclipse on a global level, open Preferences, select General/Editors/File associations tab, and assign the corresponding editor the extension (or reorder the already assigned editors).

Comment: Under preferences HTM, HTML extensions are associated with a Web Browser. What should it be?

Comment: Internal Web Browser. Or you could try to set the Default browser in General/Web Browser.

Comment: General/Web Browser are already pointing to Internal Web Browser only. I re-assigned preferences for HTM, HTML from Web Browser to Internal Web Browser, but none of these changes didn't make a difference.

Comment: Are xhtml files also directed to Internal Web Browser? In your example you stated, that you tried using those. Only file extensions are covered, file contents not when choosing an editor.

Comment: I tried using the Text editor and I guess this is what I was looking for. Added the same association for a xhtml file.